# Selection-Based Dynamic Form

Tags: forms, structure, terminology

Is there a proper term for a form that dynamically and intelligently updates it's fields based on the selection of previous fields?

For example, if **Object Type** where to be a dropdown box and **Person** and **Vehicle** where to be the options. Choosing **Person** might set the succeeding fields to *Name*, *Age*, and *Gender*, while selecting **Vehicle** would set them to *Make*, *Model*, and *Color*.

I've found plenty (and I mean PLENTY) of code pertaining to this type of form design. I came across the term "Dynamic Form" quite often in my searches, however, that seems to refer only to a form that adds/removes fields, without caring about how those fields are chosen.

Comment: dynamic form ... how you choose to handle the logic is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a technical term for it. "Dynamic Form" is the closest you'll get.